# Could the Transporters information be studied by the Science and Medical Departments?

Tags: star-trek

Is there an example of the Science or Medical Departments studying the information recorded during the beaming process to diagnose health issues among those that used the Transporter system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but onscreen it didn't happen very often.  From the [Transporter](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transporter#Transporter_trace) article on Memory Alpha:

> Transporter traces were also used as a medical tool, to help in
>   spotting anomalies at the molecular level. When comparing the
>   transporter ID traces of Deanna Troi, Data and Miles O'Brien before
>   and after they were taken over by Ux-Mal criminals, Doctor Crusher was
>   able to detect that their nervous systems were generating high levels
>   of synaptic and anionic energy. (TNG: "[Power Play](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Power_Play)") Another example of
>   such an application was in 2373, when The Doctor used Harry Kim's
>   transporter trace records to determine when he had been infected with
>   Taresian DNA. (VOY: "[Favorite Son](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Favorite_Son_%28episode%29)")

[Biofilters](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Biofilter) were part of the transporter system, so that diseases and other known pathogens were removed from the transportee before they dematerialized, making such examinations usually unnecessary.

Comment: @Thaddeus - technically speaking, being able to answer a question and considering it a good-enough-to-upvote are not necessarily correlated (This doesn't imply any opinion either way on this specific question)

Comment: Okay, perhaps its just me then. If I take the time to answer a question, I deem it worthy enough to take time out of my LIFE to render a decent answer. I figure it should get the benefit of a +1 as well. I will not push my values off on other people. Your note is appreciated.

Comment: @Thaddeus It is very rare that I +1 on questions.  Mostly because it is very rare that anyone shows that they have done the first part of the tooltip: "This question shows research effort".

Comment: @MajorStackings It is exactly as DVK said - the two are _not_ correlated.  Likewise, I'll upvote questions that I don't answer.  In this case, I answered the question because I knew the answer and there wasn't one posted yet.  However, I found the references with less than 2 minutes of searching on Google (by searching solely on terms in the question!) - which indicates to me that you didn't even try to look before you asked the question.  That is why it didn't get an upvote from me.

Comment: @Izkata It's hard to be petty and put out when the other guy is right. I know, cause I tried. I appreciate your candor. I will suggest that there are interesting questions out there people enjoy reading the answers to, even if they are easily searchable. I won't vote for every answer I get, but I do vote for questions that provoke thoughtful & entertaining answers.